# How are the docker containers scheduled?

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker

I am trying to figure out how the docker containers are scheduled.

Does anyone know which files I should read or what factors are considered when the containers are scheduled?

I am also interested in nvidia-docker and experimenting with Rodinia benchmark.
Would the size of GPU memory use be one of the factors considered when scheduling?

Opened to any suggestions about analyzing or improving docker!

Comment: What do you mean by that? Scheduled in which way?

Comment: umm.. I mean when multiple containers are started at the same time, do they run altogether by sharing gpu memory or are they executed one at a time through scheduling(ex.FIFO, Best Fit..)?

Comment: The processes in a container are executed by the host OS just like any other processes running on the machine. They share memory, CPU, ...